# Merge and Delete SQL Query

Tags: sql

Hello I'm unsure how to modify this query to DELETE records from the TARGET that no longer exist in the SOURCE. The other tricky part about this is, it can only delete records from the TARGET if the record's T.TransactionDate is less than 90 days old. I know it's a WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE, but I'm not sure how to build the rest of the query. Could anyone help me with this part?

```
MERGE TransactionData AS T
USING (SELECT * FROM Temp_TransactionData) AS S
ON (T.Transaction_ID = S.Transaction_ID AND T.Trans_Line_ID = S.Trans_Line_ID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(Account_ID, Class_ID, Company_ID, Company_Name, Design_ID, Item_ID, ItemCount, Invoice_ID, Rate, Amount, Transaction_ID, Trans_Line_ID, Transaction_Date, Transaction_Type, LicensorCode_ID, Property) VALUES(S.Account_ID, S.Class_ID, S.Company_ID, S.Company_Name, S.Design_ID, S.Item_ID, S.ItemCount, S.Invoice_ID, S.Rate, S.Amount, S.Transaction_ID, S.Trans_Line_ID, S.Transaction_Date, S.Transaction_Type, S.LicensorCode_ID, S.Property)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.Account_ID = S.Account_ID, T.Class_ID = S.Class_ID, T.Company_ID = S.Company_ID, T.Company_Name = S.Company_Name, T.Design_ID=S.Design_ID, T.Item_ID=S.Item_ID, T.ItemCount=S.ItemCount, T.Invoice_ID=S.Invoice_ID, T.Rate=S.Rate, T.Amount=S.Amount,  T.Transaction_ID=S.Transaction_ID, T.Trans_Line_ID=S.Trans_Line_ID, T.Transaction_Date=S.Transaction_Date, T.Transaction_Type=S.Transaction_Type, T.LicensorCode_ID=S.LicensorCode_ID, T.Property=S.Property;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For merge delete transactions that have T.TransactionDate 90 days or older use following.

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE and T.TransactionDate < DATEADD(d, -90, current_timestamp)
   THEN DELETE
```

Comment: I got it to work by switching the < to >. Good thing I'd made a backup before running it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    MERGE TransactionData AS T
    USING (SELECT * FROM Temp_TransactionData) AS S
    ON (T.Transaction_ID = S.Transaction_ID AND T.Trans_Line_ID = S.Trans_Line_ID) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT(Account_ID, Class_ID, Company_ID, Company_Name, Design_ID, Item_ID, ItemCount, Invoice_ID, Rate, Amount, Transaction_ID, Trans_Line_ID, Transaction_Date, Transaction_Type, LicensorCode_ID, Property) VALUES(S.Account_ID, S.Class_ID, S.Company_ID, S.Company_Name, S.Design_ID, S.Item_ID, S.ItemCount, S.Invoice_ID, S.Rate, S.Amount, S.Transaction_ID, S.Trans_Line_ID, S.Transaction_Date, S.Transaction_Type, S.LicensorCode_ID, S.Property)
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE SET T.Account_ID = S.Account_ID, T.Class_ID = S.Class_ID, T.Company_ID = S.Company_ID, T.Company_Name = S.Company_Name, T.Design_ID=S.Design_ID, T.Item_ID=S.Item_ID, T.ItemCount=S.ItemCount, T.Invoice_ID=S.Invoice_ID, T.Rate=S.Rate, T.Amount=S.Amount,  T.Transaction_ID=S.Transaction_ID, T.Trans_Line_ID=S.Trans_Line_ID, T.Transaction_Date=S.Transaction_Date, T.Transaction_Type=S.Transaction_Type, T.LicensorCode_ID=S.LicensorCode_ID, T.Property=S.Property;
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.TransactionDate <90
    THEN DELETE
```